# RSpec testing redirect to URL with GET params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, parameters, response

Let's say I have a `FoosController` with a `redirect_to_baz` method.

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController

  def redirect_to_baz
    redirect_to 'http://example.com/?foo=1&bar=2&baz=3'
  end

end
```

I'm testing this with `spec/controllers/foos_controller_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe FoosController, :type => :controller do

  describe "GET redirect_to_baz" do
    it "redirects to example.com with params" do
      get :redirect_to_baz
      expect(response).to redirect_to "http://example.com/?foo=1&bar=2&baz=3"
    end
  end

end
```

It works. However, if someone swaps the query string parameters (e.g. `http://example.com/?bar=2&baz=3&foo=1`), the test fails.

#### What's the right way of testing this?

I would like to do something like:

```
expect(response).to redirect_to("http://example.com/", params: { foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 })
```

I looked at the [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-4/docs/matchers/redirect-to-matcher) and I tried searching for `response.parameters`, but I didn't find anything like that. Even `Hash#to_query` doesn't seem to solve this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/ResponseAssertions.html#method-i-assert_redirected_to), the expected redirect path can match a regex:

```
expect(response).to redirect_to %r(\Ahttp://example.com)
```

To verify the redirect location's query string seems a little bit more convoluted. You have access to the response's location, so you should be able to do this:

```
response.location
# => http://example.com?foo=1&bar=2&baz=3
```

You should be able to extract the querystring params like this:

```
redirect_params = Rack::Utils.parse_query(URI.parse(response.location).query)
# => {"foo"=>"1", "bar"=>"2", "baz"=>"3"}
```

And from that it should be straightforward to verify that the redirect params are correct:

```
expect(redirect_params).to eq("foo" => "1", "baz" => "3", "bar" => "2")
# => true
```

If you have to do this sort of logic more than once though, it would definitely be convenient to wrap it all up into a custom rspec matcher.

Comment: `expect(response).to redirect_to(A_REGEX)` works for Rails 4 only.  For Rails 3, your best bet is probably `expect(response.location).to match(THE_REGEX)`

Answer (score 9):

Are you able to use your route helpers rather than a plain string? If so, you can just pass hash params to a route helper and they will be converted to query string params:

```
root_url foo: 'bar', baz: 'quux'
=> "http://www.your-root.com/?baz=quux&foo=bar"
expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url(foo: 'bar', baz: 'quux'))
```

Does that help, or are you restricted to using strings rather than route helpers?

Another thought is that you could just assert directly on the values in the params hash rather than the url + query string, since the query string params will get serialized into the params hash...

Comment: This has a problem in that the parameters can change order; "http://example.com/?foo=bar&baz=quux" and "http://example.com/?baz=quux&foo=bar" should be equivalent, but that expectation will only match one of them.

Comment: If the URL is being constructed with route helpers, the order is normalized and won't matter. `root_url foo: 'bar', baz: 'quux'` and `root_url baz: 'quux', foo: 'bar'` both return `"http://www.example.com/?baz=quux&foo=bar"`.

Comment: yes, they both return the same URL, but that's the problem, ideally we would want a redirect to either `http://www.your-root.com/?baz=quux&foo=bar` or `http://www.your-root.com/?foo=bar&baz=quux` to pass the test, but only one will.

Answer (score 6):

I had a need for something similar and ended up with this:

Was able to write tests and not worry about query parameter ordering.

```
expect(response.location).to be_a_similar_url_to("http://example.com/?beta=gamma&alpha=delta")
```

Drop the following into ./spec/support/matchers/be_a_similar_url_to.rb

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_a_similar_url_to do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    expected_uri = URI.parse(expected)
    actual_uri = URI.parse(actual)

    expect(actual_uri.host).to eql(expected_uri.host)
    expect(actual_uri.port).to eql(expected_uri.port)
    expect(actual_uri.scheme).to eql(expected_uri.scheme)
    expect(Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(actual_uri.query)).to eql(Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(expected_uri.query))
    expect(actual_uri.fragment).to eql(expected_uri.fragment)
  end

  # optional
  failure_message do |actual|
    "expected that #{actual} would be a similar URL to #{expected}"
  end

  # optional
  failure_message_when_negated do |actual|
    "expected that #{actual} would not be a similar URL to #{expected}"
  end
end
```