# Rspec rails: How do I test if a controller action redirects correctly to itself with modified params once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I have a controller action which (based on the query params) might redirect to itself with some modified params

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def search
    if params[:deprecated_param].present?
      params[:new_param] = params.delete(:deprecated_param)
      redirect_to search_path(params), status: :moved_permanently and return
    end
  end
end
```

Now I would like to make two tests something like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SearchController, type: :controller do
  describe 'GET #search' do
    render_views
    context 'a deprecated param is used' do
      it 'should do a redirect' do
        get :search, deprecated_param: 'yes'
        expect(response).to redirect_to("http://mydomain.test/search?new_param=yes") # .once ?
        # expect(final response after redirect).to have_http_status(200)
      end
    end
    context 'when no deprecated param is used' do
      it 'should not do any redirects' do
        get :search, new_param: 'yes'
        expect(response).not_to #... redirect_anywhere?
        expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However they don't work. There are two problems:

1. In the first test: I can't seem to test the intermediate redirection before hitting the same action again after the redirect.
2. In the second test: I can't find a way to test that no redirect happened AT ALL.

I found this related question, but it does not solve it.
[RSpec testing redirect to URL with GET params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922934/rspec-testing-redirect-to-url-with-get-params)

Comment: What happens in your controller `search` action when `deprecated_param` is not present? i.e., the `else` statement? You can directly test whatever the code you have in `else` condition as your second test. So, there will be nothing like `not_to #... redirect_anywhere?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second one I guess you can test the following things:

```
expect(response).to render_template(:your_template)
```

Just add the expected template, if you want no redirection just add the template where you expect to stay.

For the first one, I am not sure to really understand what you need but I try to advise you the following code:

```
describe SearchController, type: :request do
# ...
it 'should do a redirect' do
  get "/search", deprecated_param: 'yes'
  expect(response).to redirect_to("http://mydomain.test/search?new_param=yes")
  follow_redirect!
  expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
  expect(response).to render_template(:your_template) #just to be sur you are on the expected page
end
```

`follow_redirect!` follow a single redirect response. If the last response was not a redirect, an exception will be raised.

Comment: This works, however the spec needs to be changed from `:controller` to `:request` spec, else `follow_redirect!` does not exist.